# How to set Plone to redirect to came_from after logout

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I want to set a plone website to redirect to came_from parameter in url after user logout. For login I set `string:${globals_view/navigationRootUrl}/login?came_from=${context/absolute_url}` and it is working.

For logout this is not working. I tried also with its event:

```
  <subscriber
    for="Products.PlonePAS.events.UserLoggedOutEvent"
    handler="blabla.goCameFromAfterLogout"
    />
```

using:

```
def goCameFromAfterLogout(event):
    """ Redirects user to came_from url parameter after logout
    """
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace( )
    request = event.object.REQUEST
    came_from = request.form.get('came_from', None)
    if came_from:
        response = request.RESPONSE
        response.redirect(came_from)
```

The event is ok, the came_from parameter is ok, but the code is not working how I want.
The website redirects me to `/logged_out` every time.

So, how can I set this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way: customize `logged_out`, transform it to a Python Script that redirect to whatever page you want:

```
context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(url)
```

Comment: Where do you add this? Which file?

Comment: @codesaurusrex go to ZMI -> portal_skins -> search for "logged_out" from the "Find" tab, select it then press the "Customize" button. It will put the script in the "custom" folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can also raise a Redirect exception in your event handler

```
from zExceptions import Redirect

def goCameFromAfterLogout(event):
""" Redirects user to came_from url parameter after logout
"""
request = event.object.REQUEST
came_from = request.form.get('came_from', None)
if came_from:
    raise Redirect(came_from)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also `?next=url` instead of came_from is a good idea.